# Sidebar menu shows different movies with showDiv but movies need to reset to beginning with each click

Tags: flash, refresh

I have a sidebar menu on the left that shows different Flash movies on the right. You click on each button on the left and it replaces the currently playing movie and shows a new one using the show div function and the ReplaceContentInContainer function. The problem is that I want each movie to start at the beginning each time you click on its menu button. Here is the relevant code:

```
function showDiv(idInfo) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('divLinks').getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) { sel[i].style.display = 'none'; }
  document.getElementById('container'+idInfo).style.display = 'block';
  return false;
}

function ReplaceContentInContainer(id,content) {
var container = document.getElementById(id);
container.innerHTML = content;
}
```

And here is one of the buttons:

```
<li><span class="navtext"><a href="#" onclick="return showDiv('1')">ePRS: Account Entry        Screen</a></span></li>
```

And here is one of the container divs:

```
<div id="container1">
   <p><iframe src="http://secret.website/p62aqt113jp/" width= 1020 height = 660></iframe>
</div>
```

So, how do I get the divs to refresh and set the movies back to the start each time the user clicks?

By the way...I am not a coder...just a code copier and paster, if you know what I mean. Thanks for any help.